# Construct mesh from a point cloud

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-optimization

I have been developing a program with C lately, its purpose over the top is to reconstruct meshes from point clouds which are generated by finding the intersection points of numerous rays fired at the image which had previously been preprocessed by a HED neural-network.

I'm doing this for a school project and I haven't really been able to get used to C pretty much, which might have been the cause of me omitting some design and safety principles. According to Valgrind I have a few memory leaks, which I have trouble finding. But it's also flagging raylib's `InitWindow()` function to be leaking which leads me to believe that there might be some false positives.

```
#include <raylib.h>
#include <raymath.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

typedef struct Vertice{
    Vector2 *verticeData;
    int verticeCount;
    struct Vertice* next;
    Vector2 *intersectionPoints;
    int intersectionPointCount;
} Vertice;

typedef struct IdenticalFunction{
    Vector2 start, end;
    Color color;
} IdenticalFunction;

typedef struct IFArray{
    IdenticalFunction *identicalFunctions;
    int identicalFunctionCount;
} IFArray;

typedef struct TextureBound{
    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle rectangle;
} TextureBound;


IFArray* generateIdenticalFunctions(Vector2 worldTopLeft, Vector2 worldBottomRight){
    const int IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP = 50;
    float identicalFunctionStartX = floorf(worldTopLeft.x / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP) * IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;
    float identicalFunctionStartY = floorf(worldTopLeft.y / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP) * IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;
    int identicalFunctionCountX = (worldBottomRight.x - worldTopLeft.x) / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;
    int identicalFunctionCountY = (worldBottomRight.y - worldTopLeft.y) / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;

    IdenticalFunction *identicalFunctions = (IdenticalFunction*)malloc((identicalFunctionCountX + identicalFunctionCountY) * sizeof(IdenticalFunction));
    for(int i = 1; i < identicalFunctionCountX; i++){
        float x  = identicalFunctionStartX + (i * IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP);
        IdenticalFunction identicalFunction = {.start = (Vector2){x, worldTopLeft.y}, .end = (Vector2){x, worldBottomRight.y}, .color = RED};
        identicalFunctions[i -1] = identicalFunction;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < identicalFunctionCountY; i++){
        float y = identicalFunctionStartY + (i * IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP);
        IdenticalFunction identicalFunction = {.start = (Vector2){worldTopLeft.x, y}, .end = (Vector2){worldBottomRight.x, y}, .color = RED};
        identicalFunctions[i-1 + identicalFunctionCountX] = identicalFunction;
    }

    IFArray *ifArray = (IFArray*)malloc(sizeof(IFArray));
    ifArray->identicalFunctionCount = identicalFunctionCountX + identicalFunctionCountY;
    ifArray->identicalFunctions = identicalFunctions;

    return ifArray;
}

int main()
{
    const int WIDTH = 800;
    const int HEIGHT = 600;

    InitWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Window");

    Camera2D camera = {.offset = (Vector2){0, 0}, .target = (Vector2){0 - (float)GetScreenWidth() / 2, 0 - (float)GetScreenHeight() / 2}, .rotation = 0.0f, .zoom = 1.0f};

    SetTargetFPS(60);  
    const int CELL_SIZE = 50;
    const float ZOOM_INCREMENT = 0.125f;

    int algorithmStep = 0;

    Vertice *head = (Vertice*)malloc(sizeof(Vertice));
    head->verticeData = NULL;
    head->verticeCount = 0;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->intersectionPoints = NULL;
    head->intersectionPointCount = 0;

    Vertice *current_D = head;
    Vertice *verticeIndex = head;

    Vector2 *verticeData_G = NULL; 
    int verticeCount_G = 0;

    IFArray *ifArray_D = NULL;

    Image HED_image = LoadImage("output_hed.png");
    Texture2D HED_texture = LoadTextureFromImage(HED_image);
    UnloadImage(HED_image);
    TextureBound HED_bound = {.texture = HED_texture, .rectangle = (Rectangle){.x = 0 - HED_texture.width / 2.0f, .y = 0 - HED_texture.height / 2.0f, .width = HED_texture.width, .height = HED_texture.height}};

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(BLACK);
        BeginMode2D(camera);
        
        Vector2 cameraPosition = {camera.offset.x, camera.offset.y};
        Vector2 worldTopLeft = GetScreenToWorld2D(cameraPosition, camera);
        Vector2 worldBottomRight = GetScreenToWorld2D((Vector2){ cameraPosition.x + GetScreenWidth() / camera.zoom, cameraPosition.y + GetScreenHeight() / camera.zoom}, camera);

        float gridStartX = floorf(worldTopLeft.x / CELL_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE;
        float gridStartY = floorf(worldTopLeft.y / CELL_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE;
        
        int cellCountVER = (worldBottomRight.x - worldTopLeft.x) / CELL_SIZE;
        int cellCountHOR = (worldBottomRight.y - worldTopLeft.y) / CELL_SIZE;

        /*DrawTextureV(HED_bound.texture, (Vector2){.x = HED_bound.rectangle.x, .y = HED_bound.rectangle.y}, WHITE);
        DrawRectangleLinesEx(HED_bound.rectangle, 3.0f, RED);
        if(CheckCollisionPointRec(GetMousePosition(), HED_bound.rectangle) {
        HED_bound.rectangle.width = GetMousePosition().x - HED_bound.rectangle.x;
        HED_bound.rectangle.height = GetMousePosition().y - HED_bound.rectangle.y;
        HED_bound.texture.width = HED_bound.rectangle.width;
        HED_bound.texture.height = HED_bound.rectangle.height;
        }*/

        for (int i = 1; i < cellCountVER; i++) {
        float x = gridStartX + (i * CELL_SIZE);
        DrawLine(x, worldTopLeft.y, x, worldBottomRight.y, WHITE);
        const char* numberText = TextFormat("%d", (int)x);
        DrawText(numberText, x + 3, 3, 15, YELLOW);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < cellCountHOR; i++) {
        float y = gridStartY + (i * CELL_SIZE);
        DrawLine(worldTopLeft.x, y, worldBottomRight.x, y, WHITE);
        const char* numberText = TextFormat("%d", (int)-y);
        DrawText(numberText, 3, y + 3, 15, YELLOW);
        }

        DrawLine(worldTopLeft.x, 0, worldBottomRight.x, 0, ORANGE);
        DrawLine(0, worldTopLeft.y, 0, worldBottomRight.y, ORANGE);

        if (IsMouseButtonDown(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) && algorithmStep == 0) {
        verticeData_G = (Vector2*)realloc(verticeData_G, (verticeCount_G + 1) * sizeof(Vector2));
        verticeData_G[verticeCount_G] = GetScreenToWorld2D(GetMousePosition(), camera);
        verticeCount_G++;
        }
        if(IsMouseButtonReleased(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT)) {
        Vertice *newVertice = (Vertice*)malloc(sizeof(Vertice));
        newVertice->verticeData = (Vector2*)malloc(verticeCount_G * sizeof(Vector2));
        memcpy(newVertice->verticeData, verticeData_G, verticeCount_G * sizeof(Vector2));
        newVertice->verticeCount = verticeCount_G;
        newVertice->next = verticeIndex->next;
        newVertice->intersectionPoints = NULL;
        newVertice->intersectionPointCount = 0;

        verticeIndex->next = newVertice;
        verticeIndex = newVertice;

        verticeCount_G = 0;

        IFArray *ifArray = generateIdenticalFunctions(worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight);
        int collidingPointCount = 0;
        Vector2* collidingPoints = (Vector2*)malloc(sizeof(Vector2));
        for(int i = 0; i < verticeIndex->verticeCount - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < ifArray->identicalFunctionCount; j++){
                if(CheckCollisionLines(verticeIndex->verticeData[i], verticeIndex->verticeData[i+1], ifArray->identicalFunctions[j].start, ifArray->identicalFunctions[j].end, &collidingPoints[collidingPointCount])){
                    collidingPointCount++;
                    collidingPoints = (Vector2*)realloc(collidingPoints, (collidingPointCount + 1) * sizeof(Vector2));
                }
            }
        }

        verticeIndex->intersectionPoints = (Vector2*)malloc(collidingPointCount * sizeof(Vector2));
        memcpy(verticeIndex->intersectionPoints, collidingPoints, collidingPointCount * sizeof(Vector2));
        verticeIndex->intersectionPointCount = collidingPointCount;

        free(collidingPoints);
        free(ifArray->identicalFunctions);
        free(ifArray);
        }
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT_CONTROL) && IsKeyPressed(KEY_Z) && algorithmStep == 0){
        if(verticeIndex != head){
            Vertice *current = head;
            while(current->next != verticeIndex) current = current->next;
            verticeIndex = current;
        }
        }
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT_CONTROL) && IsKeyPressed(KEY_R) && algorithmStep == 0){
        if(verticeIndex->next != NULL) verticeIndex = verticeIndex->next;
        }

        if(algorithmStep == 2){
        for(int i = 0; i < ifArray_D->identicalFunctionCount; i++){
            DrawLineV(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions[i].start, ifArray_D->identicalFunctions[i].end, ifArray_D->identicalFunctions[i].color);
        }
        }
        if(verticeData_G != NULL) DrawLineStrip(verticeData_G, verticeCount_G, GREEN); for(int i = 0; i < verticeCount_G; i++) DrawCircleV(verticeData_G[i], 5, YELLOW);
        if(head->next != NULL){
        current_D = head->next;
        while(current_D != verticeIndex->next){
            for(int i = 0; i < current_D->verticeCount; i++) DrawCircleV(current_D->verticeData[i], 5, YELLOW);
            DrawLineStrip(current_D->verticeData, current_D->verticeCount, GREEN);

            if(algorithmStep == 2) {
                for(int i = 0; i < current_D->intersectionPointCount; i++){
                    DrawCircleV(current_D->intersectionPoints[i], 5, BLUE);
                }
            }
            current_D = current_D->next;
        }
        }

        EndDrawing();
        if (IsMouseButtonDown(MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT)){
        Vector2 delta = GetMouseDelta();
        delta = Vector2Scale(delta, -1.0f/camera.zoom);
        camera.target = Vector2Add(camera.target, delta);
        if(ifArray_D != NULL) free(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions); free(ifArray_D);
        ifArray_D = generateIdenticalFunctions(worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight);
        }
        float wheel = GetMouseWheelMove();
        if (wheel != 0){            
        camera.zoom += (wheel*ZOOM_INCREMENT);
        if (camera.zoom < ZOOM_INCREMENT) camera.zoom = ZOOM_INCREMENT;
        if (camera.zoom > 1) camera.zoom = 1;
        if(ifArray_D != NULL) free(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions); free(ifArray_D);
        ifArray_D = generateIdenticalFunctions(worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight);
        }
        if(IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE)){
        if(ifArray_D != NULL) free(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions); free(ifArray_D);
        ifArray_D = generateIdenticalFunctions(worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight);
        algorithmStep = 2;
        }

    }

    UnloadTexture(HED_texture);
    free(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions);
    free(ifArray_D);
    Vertice *current_F = head;
    Vertice *next_F;
    while(current_F != NULL){
        next_F = current_F->next;
        free(current_F->verticeData);
        free(current_F->intersectionPoints);
        free(current_F);
        current_F = next_F;
    }
    free(verticeData_G);

    CloseWindow();       
    return 0;
}
```

The  [`output_hed.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEpxg.png) file is a white/transparent image thus:
[image: output_hed.png]

Comment: Is a suitable `output_hed.png` file available online so that reviewers can experiment with the code?

Comment: I've just added it, it's completely white and a PNG, so it might be hard to notice, but it's under the code section.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, the indentation of this code is a mess, which is probably due to the use of tabs for indentation.  Should I fix that for you?

Comment: Oh sorry, don't bother yourself with it, they mostly occurred when porting from nvim to the site, they don't look like that

Answer (score 6):

The OP code is illegible, with no tabs, so after a clang-format pass
I reviewed the following code instead.

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <raylib.h>
#include <raymath.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Vertice {
    Vector2 *verticeData;
    int verticeCount;
    struct Vertice *next;
    Vector2 *intersectionPoints;
    int intersectionPointCount;
} Vertice;

typedef struct IdenticalFunction {
    Vector2 start, end;
    Color color;
} IdenticalFunction;

typedef struct IFArray {
    IdenticalFunction *identicalFunctions;
    int identicalFunctionCount;
} IFArray;

typedef struct TextureBound {
    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle rectangle;
} TextureBound;

IFArray *generateIdenticalFunctions(Vector2 worldTopLeft,
                                    Vector2 worldBottomRight) {
    const int IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP = 50;
    float identicalFunctionStartX =
        floorf(worldTopLeft.x / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP) *
        IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;
    float identicalFunctionStartY =
        floorf(worldTopLeft.y / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP) *
        IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;
    int identicalFunctionCountX =
        (worldBottomRight.x - worldTopLeft.x) / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;
    int identicalFunctionCountY =
        (worldBottomRight.y - worldTopLeft.y) / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;

    IdenticalFunction *identicalFunctions = (IdenticalFunction *)malloc(
        (identicalFunctionCountX + identicalFunctionCountY) *
        sizeof(IdenticalFunction));
    for (int i = 1; i < identicalFunctionCountX; i++) {
        float x = identicalFunctionStartX + (i * IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP);
        IdenticalFunction identicalFunction = {
            .start = (Vector2){x, worldTopLeft.y},
            .end = (Vector2){x, worldBottomRight.y},
            .color = RED};
        identicalFunctions[i - 1] = identicalFunction;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < identicalFunctionCountY; i++) {
        float y = identicalFunctionStartY + (i * IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP);
        IdenticalFunction identicalFunction = {
            .start = (Vector2){worldTopLeft.x, y},
            .end = (Vector2){worldBottomRight.x, y},
            .color = RED};
        identicalFunctions[i - 1 + identicalFunctionCountX] = identicalFunction;
    }

    IFArray *ifArray = (IFArray *)malloc(sizeof(IFArray));
    ifArray->identicalFunctionCount =
        identicalFunctionCountX + identicalFunctionCountY;
    ifArray->identicalFunctions = identicalFunctions;

    return ifArray;
}

int main() {
    const int WIDTH = 800;
    const int HEIGHT = 600;

    InitWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Window");

    Camera2D camera = {.offset = (Vector2){0, 0},
                       .target = (Vector2){0 - (float)GetScreenWidth() / 2,
                                           0 - (float)GetScreenHeight() / 2},
                       .rotation = 0.0f,
                       .zoom = 1.0f};

    SetTargetFPS(60);
    const int CELL_SIZE = 50;
    const float ZOOM_INCREMENT = 0.125f;

    int algorithmStep = 0;

    Vertice *head = (Vertice *)malloc(sizeof(Vertice));
    head->verticeData = NULL;
    head->verticeCount = 0;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->intersectionPoints = NULL;
    head->intersectionPointCount = 0;

    Vertice *current_D = head;
    Vertice *verticeIndex = head;

    Vector2 *verticeData_G = NULL;
    int verticeCount_G = 0;

    IFArray *ifArray_D = NULL;

    Image HED_image = LoadImage("output_hed.png");
    Texture2D HED_texture = LoadTextureFromImage(HED_image);
    UnloadImage(HED_image);
    TextureBound HED_bound = {
        .texture = HED_texture,
        .rectangle = (Rectangle){.x = 0 - HED_texture.width / 2.0f,
                                 .y = 0 - HED_texture.height / 2.0f,
                                 .width = HED_texture.width,
                                 .height = HED_texture.height}};

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(BLACK);
        BeginMode2D(camera);

        Vector2 cameraPosition = {camera.offset.x, camera.offset.y};
        Vector2 worldTopLeft = GetScreenToWorld2D(cameraPosition, camera);
        Vector2 worldBottomRight = GetScreenToWorld2D(
            (Vector2){cameraPosition.x + GetScreenWidth() / camera.zoom,
                      cameraPosition.y + GetScreenHeight() / camera.zoom},
            camera);

        float gridStartX = floorf(worldTopLeft.x / CELL_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE;
        float gridStartY = floorf(worldTopLeft.y / CELL_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE;

        int cellCountVER = (worldBottomRight.x - worldTopLeft.x) / CELL_SIZE;
        int cellCountHOR = (worldBottomRight.y - worldTopLeft.y) / CELL_SIZE;

        /*DrawTextureV(HED_bound.texture, (Vector2){.x = HED_bound.rectangle.x,
        .y = HED_bound.rectangle.y}, WHITE);
        DrawRectangleLinesEx(HED_bound.rectangle, 3.0f, RED);
        if(CheckCollisionPointRec(GetMousePosition(), HED_bound.rectangle) {
        HED_bound.rectangle.width = GetMousePosition().x -
        HED_bound.rectangle.x; HED_bound.rectangle.height = GetMousePosition().y
        - HED_bound.rectangle.y; HED_bound.texture.width =
        HED_bound.rectangle.width; HED_bound.texture.height =
        HED_bound.rectangle.height;
        }*/

        for (int i = 1; i < cellCountVER; i++) {
            float x = gridStartX + (i * CELL_SIZE);
            DrawLine(x, worldTopLeft.y, x, worldBottomRight.y, WHITE);
            const char *numberText = TextFormat("%d", (int)x);
            DrawText(numberText, x + 3, 3, 15, YELLOW);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < cellCountHOR; i++) {
            float y = gridStartY + (i * CELL_SIZE);
            DrawLine(worldTopLeft.x, y, worldBottomRight.x, y, WHITE);
            const char *numberText = TextFormat("%d", (int)-y);
            DrawText(numberText, 3, y + 3, 15, YELLOW);
        }

        DrawLine(worldTopLeft.x, 0, worldBottomRight.x, 0, ORANGE);
        DrawLine(0, worldTopLeft.y, 0, worldBottomRight.y, ORANGE);

        if (IsMouseButtonDown(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) && algorithmStep == 0) {
            verticeData_G = (Vector2 *)realloc(
                verticeData_G, (verticeCount_G + 1) * sizeof(Vector2));
            verticeData_G[verticeCount_G] =
                GetScreenToWorld2D(GetMousePosition(), camera);
            verticeCount_G++;
        }
        if (IsMouseButtonReleased(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT)) {
            Vertice *newVertice = (Vertice *)malloc(sizeof(Vertice));
            newVertice->verticeData =
                (Vector2 *)malloc(verticeCount_G * sizeof(Vector2));
            memcpy(newVertice->verticeData, verticeData_G,
                   verticeCount_G * sizeof(Vector2));
            newVertice->verticeCount = verticeCount_G;
            newVertice->next = verticeIndex->next;
            newVertice->intersectionPoints = NULL;
            newVertice->intersectionPointCount = 0;

            verticeIndex->next = newVertice;
            verticeIndex = newVertice;

            verticeCount_G = 0;

            IFArray *ifArray =
                generateIdenticalFunctions(worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight);
            int collidingPointCount = 0;
            Vector2 *collidingPoints = (Vector2 *)malloc(sizeof(Vector2));
            for (int i = 0; i < verticeIndex->verticeCount - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < ifArray->identicalFunctionCount; j++) {
                    if (CheckCollisionLines(
                            verticeIndex->verticeData[i],
                            verticeIndex->verticeData[i + 1],
                            ifArray->identicalFunctions[j].start,
                            ifArray->identicalFunctions[j].end,
                            &collidingPoints[collidingPointCount])) {
                        collidingPointCount++;
                        collidingPoints = (Vector2 *)realloc(
                            collidingPoints,
                            (collidingPointCount + 1) * sizeof(Vector2));
                    }
                }
            }

            verticeIndex->intersectionPoints =
                (Vector2 *)malloc(collidingPointCount * sizeof(Vector2));
            memcpy(verticeIndex->intersectionPoints, collidingPoints,
                   collidingPointCount * sizeof(Vector2));
            verticeIndex->intersectionPointCount = collidingPointCount;

            free(collidingPoints);
            free(ifArray->identicalFunctions);
            free(ifArray);
        }
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT_CONTROL) && IsKeyPressed(KEY_Z) &&
            algorithmStep == 0) {
            if (verticeIndex != head) {
                Vertice *current = head;
                while (current->next != verticeIndex) {
                    current = current->next;
                }
                verticeIndex = current;
            }
        }
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT_CONTROL) && IsKeyPressed(KEY_R) &&
            algorithmStep == 0) {
            if (verticeIndex->next != NULL) {
                verticeIndex = verticeIndex->next;
            }
        }

        if (algorithmStep == 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ifArray_D->identicalFunctionCount; i++) {
                DrawLineV(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions[i].start,
                          ifArray_D->identicalFunctions[i].end,
                          ifArray_D->identicalFunctions[i].color);
            }
        }
        if (verticeData_G != NULL) {
            DrawLineStrip(verticeData_G, verticeCount_G, GREEN);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < verticeCount_G; i++) {
            DrawCircleV(verticeData_G[i], 5, YELLOW);
        }
        if (head->next != NULL) {
            current_D = head->next;
            while (current_D != verticeIndex->next) {
                for (int i = 0; i < current_D->verticeCount; i++) {
                    DrawCircleV(current_D->verticeData[i], 5, YELLOW);
                }
                DrawLineStrip(current_D->verticeData, current_D->verticeCount,
                              GREEN);

                if (algorithmStep == 2) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < current_D->intersectionPointCount;
                         i++) {
                        DrawCircleV(current_D->intersectionPoints[i], 5, BLUE);
                    }
                }
                current_D = current_D->next;
            }
        }

        EndDrawing();
        if (IsMouseButtonDown(MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT)) {
            Vector2 delta = GetMouseDelta();
            delta = Vector2Scale(delta, -1.0f / camera.zoom);
            camera.target = Vector2Add(camera.target, delta);
            if (ifArray_D != NULL) {
                free(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions);
            }
            free(ifArray_D);
            ifArray_D =
                generateIdenticalFunctions(worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight);
        }
        float wheel = GetMouseWheelMove();
        if (wheel != 0) {
            camera.zoom += (wheel * ZOOM_INCREMENT);
            if (camera.zoom < ZOOM_INCREMENT) {
                camera.zoom = ZOOM_INCREMENT;
            }
            if (camera.zoom > 1) {
                camera.zoom = 1;
            }
            if (ifArray_D != NULL) {
                free(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions);
            }
            free(ifArray_D);
            ifArray_D =
                generateIdenticalFunctions(worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight);
        }
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE)) {
            if (ifArray_D != NULL) {
                free(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions);
            }
            free(ifArray_D);
            ifArray_D =
                generateIdenticalFunctions(worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight);
            algorithmStep = 2;
        }
    }

    UnloadTexture(HED_texture);
    free(ifArray_D->identicalFunctions);
    free(ifArray_D);
    Vertice *current_F = head;
    Vertice *next_F;
    while (current_F != NULL) {
        next_F = current_F->next;
        free(current_F->verticeData);
        free(current_F->intersectionPoints);
        free(current_F);
        current_F = next_F;
    }
    free(verticeData_G);

    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

---

When reviewing I always assume the original author
got it to run, pass unit tests, and so on.
For C code we typically assume at least "-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic".
But I don't see the `floorf()` call
accompanied by `#include <math.h>` :-(  Perhaps including
[raymath](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raymath.h)
suffices.

---

```
typedef struct Vertice {
```

Singular of vertices?
Other than that *one time* Cicero used it this way,
conventionally the singular is `Vertex`.
Oh, well, we'll roll with it.

```
typedef struct IdenticalFunction {
```

What a curious name!
Definitely this is not a "function".
Perhaps we have an `EqualityResult`?

I see five integers, there.
I wonder if we could boil them down to a single hash,
if equality ("identicalness"?) is all that matters.

```
    IdenticalFunction *identicalFunctions;
```

zomg, "you are lost in a twisty maze of functions,
[all identical](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Zork_I:_The_Great_Underground_Empire/Walkthrough#The_Maze)".

---

```
IFArray *generateIdenticalFunctions(Vector2 worldTopLeft,
                                    Vector2 worldBottomRight) {
```

Maybe this could be `generateHashes`? Ok, I'll drop it.

Kudos on lovely parameter names.
Often this would be `worldTL, worldBR`, but these names are nicer.

```
    float identicalFunctionStartX =
        floorf(worldTopLeft.x / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP) *
        IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;
```

I guess I'd be a little happier with `gridStartX`,
since we're discretizing to a grid of 50.
Consider introducing a macro / function named `discretize()`,
which we use the same for X and Y.

```
    int identicalFunctionCountX =
        (worldBottomRight.x - worldTopLeft.x) / IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP;
```

I don't understand what this means.
In particular, it is not yet clear to me if there is some
special relationship between numerator and denominator.
Was there maybe a fractional part that was truncated to `int`?
I would love to see a `// comment` about whether we
expect that last grid to contain exactly zero pixels.

The bigger critique of this chunk of code is I would love
to see it introduce a vocabulary word,
a coarse grained `grid`, for the business concept we're describing here.

A similar approach would describe this as a mapping between a
pair of related coordinate systems.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < identicalFunctionCountX; i++) {
        ...
        identicalFunctions[i - 1] = identicalFunction;
```

Uggh! You lost me there.
Why didn't we start at `0`?
Why didn't we fill in the final grid?

DRY, same as above, couldn't an X macro or function
be recycled for the Y axis?

We seem to be returning a bunch of vertical bands
followed by many horizontal bands.
The identifiers and the comments didn't really spell that out for us.

---

```
int main() {
```

zomg, it just never ends, does it?
There's more than 200 LOC here.
I haven't read one of them and already I'm
crying out for "extract helper!"

Kudos on appropriately naming each
[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Although `CELL_SIZE` seems suspciously similar
to `IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP`.

```
    Vertice *head = ...
```

This is a terrific opportunity for Extract Helper.

I'm sure "D" and "G" are meaningful,
but I confess that ATM I have no idea
what `current_D` and `verticeData_G` denote.

```
    Texture2D HED_texture = ...
```

Consider extracting a helper here.

What is `HED_bound` for? It doesn't appear to be used.
I don't *think* we evaluated for side effects??

Actually, some of the code so far could perhaps be safely deleted.
Similarly the `/*DrawTextureV ... */` remark.
It may have been useful once,
but now you're getting ready to merge down to `main`
so it's time to prune away old cruft.

---

```
... GetScreenToWorld2D(
            (Vector2){cameraPosition.x + GetScreenWidth() / camera.zoom,
                      cameraPosition.y + GetScreenHeight() / camera.zoom}, ...
```

Oooh, lookit that!
Another transform from one coordinate system to another.
It's an important concept, so consider using a helper to clarify it.

```
        float gridStartX = floorf(worldTopLeft.x / CELL_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE;
```

Back to discretizing.
"grid"? "cell"?
Both are good names.
I encourage you to pick one and standardize on just that.

---

```
            DrawText(numberText, x + 3, 3, 15, YELLOW);
```

Names for those magic numbers, please.

We're processing both vertical and horizontal bands.
A single helper should be able to accomplish both tasks.

---

```
    int algorithmStep = 0;
```

Possibly we want a descriptive enum for that?

```
            verticeCount_G++;
```

Consider replacing that with a pre-increment:

```
            ... realloc(
                verticeData_G, (--verticeCount_G) * sizeof(Vector2));
```

```
            Vertice *newVertice = ...
```

Another good place to introduce a helper.
Similarly for your computation of `collidingPointCount`.

```
                        collidingPointCount++;
                        collidingPoints = (Vector2 *)realloc(
                            collidingPoints,
                            (collidingPointCount + 1) * sizeof(Vector2));
```

Similar idiom as above, but phrased slightly differently.
I don't understand the `+ 1` here.
Surely the increment above took care of that?
Oh, no it didn't.
There's an invariant here, and it is correctly
preserved, I just didn't read it properly the first time through,
because the names are a little tricky and imply
a situation that is off-by-one from what we've actually stored.
Sigh.

The final malloc / memcpy is nice enough.
But maybe it could be replaced by a simple pointer assignment?

---

We need a helper that will free `ifArray_D->identicalFunctions`
and `ifArray_D`.

```
            algorithmStep = 2;
```

Give that obscure step a name, please.

Kudos on the orderly shutdown.
It's nice to see everything carefully free'd.
I wonder if raylib perhaps has some shutdown()
function you'd like to call?

---

This code achieves most of its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept
maintenance tasks on this codebase.

Comment: I tab-expanded the code in the question to fix the formatting whilst you were writing this answer.  That may invalidate some of your first point - please check.

Comment: Hi, @J_H To clarify a few misunderstandings, the struct "IdenticalFunction" is literary my implementation of "f(x) = c "though in some cases it's rather a relation between sets than a function because in some cases it does not have a single "y" value for a single "x" value but the opposite. Oversimplified, it's a line with zero or undefined curvature. Next, "identicalFunctionStartX" and "gridStartX" must be two separate terms because I want the user to be able to change "IDENTICAL_FUNCTION_GAP" to allow faster but less precise collision checks or vice versa. PART 1

Comment: It also baffled you why I started the "for loop" from "1" instead of "0", that's because as you might have guessed we only need "n-1" cuts to divide an entirety into "n" parts. Also, to clear the naming conventions "_D" and "_G" they stand for "Drawing" and "Global"  they are simply my solution to overcome some problems with linked lists, though I can imagine that they are bad practice. Lastly, "HED_bound" is there because I needed to obtain the world position of the "HED_texture" which was not a variable of it, so I created a struct which had a bounding rectangle of the texture. PART 2

Comment: Now what I didn't understand was the term "extract helper", seriously, what is it? I also didn't understand why you pre-dencremented the "verticeCount_G" variable? Could you elaborate a little further on them?

The codebase had some changes as well, here's the repo: https://github.com/Di0n-0/Lineal-V2

P.S.

I could very much use some well-needed help with the project, I feel like I bit a lot more than I chew with C. PART 3

Comment: Thank you, @TobySpeight. The OP posted v1 and you posted v6 with some extra whitespace. I'm unwilling to believe that either one of them are what OP would see in his IDE; there is loss in translation. For example at one point we have 3 + 1 conjuncts, for mouse-left & KEY_Z & step0 + "are we at head?". They're all at same level, with a pair of `}` braces directly above one another. It seems like we were about to combine it into a single `if` with 4 conjuncts, then bailed at the last moment. Similarly for step2 + `for` loop, and for "next non-null" + `while`. Code was _almost_ ready for review.

Comment: @Di0n, the `collidingPointCount` code is not exactly baffling, but it wasn't obvious upon first reading either. There are two distinct concepts: "how many points collide?" and "how many points are allocated?" That last one is either +0 or +1 from your integer counter. The desire to have `CheckCollisionLines` append to a container it does not own muddied the waters a bit. An alternate design would allocate a single temporary location, and conditionally memcpy the result to end of container. // As far as "extract helper" goes, it asks that you break out a small function, to shrink `main()`.

Comment: @J_H thank you for the clarification, I avoided extracting helpers when I wrote the code to avoid having to pass parameters, but that was foul of me. I will refactor it as soon as possible. A topic which I'm still curious about is though whether you ran any memory tests I think my valgrind runs gave me false positives.

Comment: I don't have the right environment, including a raylib installation, to run this code. I usually approach a review task by trying to answer just two questions: (1) is this code _obviously_ correct? (2) is it maintainable? I figure that other goals, like running automated unit tests, have already been accomplished by the original author. If code is correct but not obviously so, I tend to complain / ruminate / think aloud about what I heard the code tell me, in case the author had some different intent. I feel that just knowing some Reader hit a speedbump is valuable feedback for future writing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to pick on a single line here; many of the points apply throughout:

> ```
> collidingPoints = (Vector2*)realloc(collidingPoints, (collidingPointCount + 1) * sizeof(Vector2));
> ```

There's no need to cast the return value from the `malloc()` family of functions - they return `void*`, which is directly convertible to any object pointer in C.

As a style matter, it's good practice to use the `sizeof` the actual pointed-to element so that the reader can instantly see it's a match without having to search for the declaration.  And it's good to have the `sizeof` expression first (which can avoid arithmetic overflow problems in some circumstances).

We really need to check that we didn't get a null pointer back before we use it.  And if it's null, we shouldn't overwrite `collidingPoints`, as that's the one remaining pointer that can be used to free the memory we have - without that, we're condemned to have a leak.

The usual control flow for such reallocation is:

```
void *new_p = realloc(p, sizeof *p * new_element_count);
if (!new_p) {
    free(p);
    /* Add any other clean-up here. */
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
   /* EXIT_FAILURE is appropriate for main().
      For other functions, follow local conventions. */
}
p = new_p;
```

Comment: Thanks for your criticism and corrections, as for your first point I didn't really understand where in my code base a different sizeof() operation is used than the pointed to element/s could you clarify that for me? As for your second point, my goal was to well kind of implement the std::vector logic from cpp there like a dynamically allocated Vector2 array, was my mistake only that I did not check if it's null or not?

Comment: You used `sizeof (Vector2)`, which requires the reader to go back and confirm that that's the right size for `*collidingPoints`.  Using `sizeof` with a type argument is usually inferior to using it with an expression argument.  See how `p = malloc(sizeof *p)` is very obviously consistent, even if the declaration of `p` isn't visible?

Comment: Two mistakes - not checking whether the returned pointer is null, and assigning it before the check.  If `realloc(p, new_size)` returns a null pointer, the memory pointed to by `p` is unchanged, so `p = realloc()` leaves us with no way to `free()` it.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it now